# Creating Dynamic Partitions in Hive is taking too much time

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a parquet hive table which has date and hour as the partitioning columns. My spark job runs at an interval of 3 hours. Everytime it runs, it creates dynamic partitions. The job gets completed fast but the creation of partitions takes a lot of time. Is there any way by which we can fasten this process ?

Comment: Are you writing data to HDFS or any other file system? and any idea how many partitions it might create every time the job completes execution?

Comment: @Naga I am writing data to HDFS. On an average, it creates about 5-6 partitions. But the data size is big.

Comment: May I know how much time it's taking and the approximate size of data?

Comment: @Naga , it takes about 15 minutes for the insertInto hive table task and 1.5 hours to create the dynamic partitions. In every run, the data is about 700 GB

Comment: It seems like the time taken is for copying data to its corresponding partitions. If there are many small files or many partitions are there, try reducing the number of partitions.

Comment: @user2597100 Thanks it looks like it's longer time ; for example we insert 1 TB ( without replication) data in 45 partitions within a min. Is it possible to see how you're inserting data ( query) and any properties you're passing while executing the query

Comment: @Naga are the partitions dynamically created or are they static partitions ? Here is my query -  dataFrame.coalesce(1000).write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("tableName")

Comment: My case is entirely different mine is Hive dynamic partitioning that's the reason I was asking for code .. is this all your code? how are you dividing output file to partitions?